# Using ldflags for embedding build info into binaries

Tags: go, build, linker

I've started playing with the linker flags to try to embed version and build info into binaries at compile time. It seemed pretty straight forward, but it was not working the way I thought it would. Here is the case:

I usually structure my repos that have multiple build artifacts using the cmd/bins pattern, like so:

```
repo
├── go.mod
└── cmd 
    ├── project1 
    └── project2
```

And this is my `go.mod` file:

```
module repo

go 1.21.0
```

Each of these projects is a `main` package, with some global uninitialized variables waiting to be set by the `ldflags`. So I prepared the build command like this:

```
go build -ldflags="-X 'repo/cmd/project1/main.BuildTime=2023-10-24 14:22' \
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/main.GitCommit=648c53d' \
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/main.GoVersion=go1.21.0' \
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/main.OsArch=arm64' \
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/main.OsName=darwin' \
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/main.VersionMetadata=' \
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/main.FullVersion=v0.0.0'" \
./cmd/project1
```

The thing is that it doesn't work. after the build, when reading these variables, they are always empty. But if I do the same for a main package that is at the root of the repository, it works and I don't even need to reference the full import path, just `-X main.GitCommit=648c53d` will do, for example. For this structure I've been using, the only way I could make it work was by adding a `version` package for each project, like so:

```
repo
├── go.mod
└── cmd
    ├── project1
    │   └── version
    └── project2
        └── version
```

and by setting the variables now defined at each version package level with:

```
go build -ldflags="-X 'repo/cmd/project1/version.BuildTime=2023-10-24 14:22' \
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/version.GitCommit=648c53d'
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/version.GoVersion=go1.21.0'
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/version.OsArch=arm64'
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/version.OsName=darwin'
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/version.VersionMetadata='
-X 'repo/cmd/project1/version.FullVersion=v0.0.0'"
./cmd/project1
```

The question is: why doesn't it work when the variables are set on the `project1` package level? Is it a linker limitation? I'd appreciate any info that can help me understand what is happening here.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, but I think your problem is that `-X` is defined as working on a "import path", not a relative directory. The import path for `main` is always just `main`, because nothing can import it.

Comment: In the example above repo also represents the module name. I'll edit the question to make it clear. But either way, I was already working with the full import paths for both modules in the cmd directory, the linker only won't accept referencing the main module in that path.

Comment: yes, because `"repo/cmd/project1/main"` is not a valid _import_ path, you cannot import that path. From the linker's perspective the main module is always `main`.

Comment: Oh, man. NOW I get it. These silly things still get me from time to time. Thank you!

Comment: Note that path for your main package (or any package) doesn't contain the package name appended to the path, `"repo/cmd/project1"` is the actual name of that `main` package, just like what you would use for `go install`.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Makefile:

```
FLAGS = -ldflags="-X '$(PATH)/intrl/app.Build=$(BUILD)'"
```

where I define `PATH` as `github.com/user/project`

then in `intrl/app/version.go`

```
package intrl

var Build = ""
```